# Sktime - how to make in-sample and out-of-sample forecasts with exogenous variables?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to make forecasts using sktime for my entire training data and an arbitrary length of out-of-sample data but can't figure it out.

```py
# Generate 2 years of daily data
data = np.random.random(365 * 2,)
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': data})
# Arbirtrary X variable (8% per year growth as a daily increase)
df['daily_growth'] = 8 / 365 

# Forecast for entire dataset and 1 year into the future
fh = np.arange(-len(df)+1, 365+1)
# Fit model
arima = AutoARIMA()
arima.fit(df.y, X=df.daily_growth)
# Create forecast df for in-sample and out-of-sample data... 
# ...this is probably where the problem lies
forecast_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(fh))) # `index=fh` also fails
forecast_df['daily_growth'] = 8 / 365
# ValueError...
preds_with_X = arima.predict(fh=fh, X=forecast_df)
```

Output

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 15>()
     13 preds_no_X = arima_no_X.predict(fh=fh)
     14 len(fh) == len(forecast_df)
---> 15 preds_with_X = arima_with_X.predict(fh=fh, X=forecast_df)
     17 plt.plot(df.y, label='Actual')
     18 plt.plot(preds_no_X, label='preds_no_X')

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/humbl_keywords/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktime/forecasting/base/_base.py:318, in BaseForecaster.predict(self, fh, X)
    316 # we call the ordinary _predict if no looping/vectorization needed
    317 if not self._is_vectorized:
--> 318     y_pred = self._predict(fh=fh, X=X_inner)
    319 else:
    320     # otherwise we call the vectorized version of predict
    321     y_pred = self._vectorize("predict", X=X_inner, fh=fh)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/humbl_keywords/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktime/forecasting/base/adapters/_pmdarima.py:84, in _PmdArimaAdapter._predict(self, fh, X)
     81 # both in-sample and out-of-sample values
     82 else:
     83     y_ins = self._predict_in_sample(fh_ins, X=X)
---> 84     y_oos = self._predict_fixed_cutoff(fh_oos, X=X)
     85     return pd.concat([y_ins, y_oos])

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/humbl_keywords/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sktime/forecasting/base/adapters/_pmdarima.py:177, in _PmdArimaAdapter._predict_fixed_cutoff(self, fh, X, return_pred_int, alpha)
    162 """Make predictions out of sample.
    163 
    164 Parameters
   (...)
    174 Returns series of predicted values.
    175 """
    176 n_periods = int(fh.to_relative(self.cutoff)[-1])
--> 177 result = self._forecaster.predict(
    178     n_periods=n_periods,
    179     X=X,
    180     return_conf_int=False,
    181     alpha=DEFAULT_ALPHA,
    182 )
    184 fh_abs = fh.to_absolute(self.cutoff)
    185 fh_idx = fh.to_indexer(self.cutoff)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/humbl_keywords/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pmdarima/utils/metaestimators.py:53, in _IffHasDelegate.__get__.<locals>.<lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
     50         attrgetter(self.delegate_names[-1])(obj)
     52 # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
---> 53 out = (lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs))
     54 # update the docstring of the returned function
     55 update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/humbl_keywords/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pmdarima/arima/auto.py:257, in AutoARIMA.predict(self, n_periods, X, return_conf_int, alpha, **kwargs)
    247 @if_has_delegate("model_")
    248 def predict(self,
    249             n_periods=10,
   (...)
    254 
    255     # Temporary shim until we remove `exogenous` support completely
    256     X, _ = pm_compat.get_X(X, **kwargs)
--> 257     return self.model_.predict(
    258         n_periods=n_periods,
    259         X=X,
    260         return_conf_int=return_conf_int,
    261         alpha=alpha,
    262     )

File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/humbl_keywords/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pmdarima/arima/arima.py:785, in ARIMA.predict(self, n_periods, X, return_conf_int, alpha, **kwargs)
    783 X = self._check_exog(X)  # type: np.ndarray
    784 if X is not None and X.shape[0] != n_periods:
--> 785     raise ValueError('X array dims (n_rows) != n_periods')
    787 # f = self.arima_res_.forecast(steps=n_periods, exog=X)
    788 arima = self.arima_res_

ValueError: X array dims (n_rows) != n_periods
```

Alas, `pmdarima` doesn't print what input it receives for `n_rows` and `n_periods`. But I think I am passing the correct shapes.

```py
len(fh) == len(forecast_df)  # True
fh.shape, forecast_df.shape  # ((1095,), (1095, 1))
```

P.S. I'm not sure my `daily_growth` var would actually have any impact on the results. Advice on this point and how to get the model to have 8% growth would be helpful too!

Answer (score 1):

**short answer:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69974021/10452700) they proposed to use:

> This is the correct way to generate predictions by providing the *exogenous* data:
>
> ```py
> forecast = model.predict(n_periods=len(df_test), >exogenous=df_test[exogenous_features])
> ```
>
> When you are missing the exogenous data, hence the error (X array should contain >your exogenous_features):
>
> ```py
> model.predict(n_periods=365)
> ```

---

**Long answer:**

In my experiment to reach [**out-of-sample forecasting**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/261594/240550) (predicting beyond the training dataset) over future data (unseen test-set), I separated your generated data into train, test.

There are lots of posts without accepted answers for this topic.

- [Time series forecast for everyday for till a distant future](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/76979/69263)
- [A timestep's prediction depends on future data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/36640/69263)
- 

There is no solid guide on how one can use [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) regressors for the concept of *out-of-sample forecasting*:

- [Simple prediction using linear regression with python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29623171/10452700)
- [True out-of-sample forecasting of time series in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61460607/10452700)

Nevertheless, I found some good workarounds like:

- [image: img]

> ...model generates forecasts for the next 7 days, only the 7-day-ahead forecast makes efficient use of the past data [ref](https://regressit.com/forecasting.html)

I checked [sktime](/questions/tagged/sktime) package [documentation](https://www.sktime.net/en/latest/examples/01_forecasting.html), but I could not find how one can use *out-of-sample* using this library as well as [skforecast](/questions/tagged/skforecast) documentation.

Note: As it is mentioned [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-sample-forecasts-arima-python/) by *Jason Brownlee*, one of the approaches is *Multi-Step Out-of-Sample Forecast* which is available in  [skforecast](/questions/tagged/skforecast) lib under the title of [*Recursive multi-step forecasting*](https://skforecast.org/0.9.1/user_guides/autoregresive-forecaster) which you can see how:

> Time series transformation, including an **exogenous** variable.

It is **unclear** to me which parameter (maybe `lag` or `step` in [skforecast](/questions/tagged/skforecast)) in those packages we should use with(out) *exogenous* variable to achieve *out-of-sample forecasting* i.e. for the next 10 steps.

just note that [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/tbierhance/perils-of-recursive-forecasting) there is good workaround about impact of *exogenous* variable.

Some mainly old ARIMA-related posts help for our goal:

- [How to forecast a time series out-of-sample using an ARIMA model in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67099991/10452700)
- [Creating an out of sample forecast in Python based on ARIMA model built on train and test data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68500509/10452700)
- [ARMA out-of-sample prediction with statsmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18616588/10452700)
- [True out-of-sample forecasting of time series in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61460607/10452700)
- [ARMA.predict for out-of sample forecast does not work with floating points?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27931571/10452700)

I just found ARIMA-based [example](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/auto_examples/arima/example_add_new_samples.html) in [sktime](/questions/tagged/sktime) package that corresponds clearly to the parameter of **out-of-sample**: `out_of_sample_size=10` as follows:

```py
#!pip install sktime
#!pip install pmdarima
#!pip install sktime[all_extras]
import warnings
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pmdarima as pm
from pmdarima import model_selection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# hide warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Generate data
data = np.random.random(365 * 2,)
df   = pd.DataFrame({'y': data})
df['daily_growth'] = np.random.random(365 * 2,)
#fh = [1,2,3,4] #forecast horizon object

#df
###################################
#|    |        y |   daily_growth |
#|---:|---------:|---------------:|
#|  0 | 0.213322 |     0.394769   |
#|  1 | 0.878436 |     0.00674871 |
#|  2 | 0.174274 |     0.759531   |
#|  3 | 0.212685 |     0.23475    |
#|  4 | 0.86434  |     0.0325546  |

# #############################################################################
# Load the data and split it into separate pieces
train, test = model_selection.train_test_split(data, train_size=600)

# #############################################################################
# Fit with some validation (cv) samples
arima = pm.auto_arima(train, start_p=1, start_q=1, d=0, max_p=5, max_q=5,
                      out_of_sample_size=10, suppress_warnings=True,
                      stepwise=True, error_action='ignore')

# Now plot the results and the forecast for the test set
preds, conf_int = arima.predict(n_periods=test.shape[0],
                                return_conf_int=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 8))


x_axis = np.arange(train.shape[0] + preds.shape[0])
axes[0].plot(x_axis[:train.shape[0]], train, alpha=0.75 , label='train')
axes[0].scatter(x_axis[train.shape[0]:], preds, alpha=0.4, marker='o', label='forecast' ,color='m')
axes[0].scatter(x_axis[train.shape[0]:], test, alpha=0.4, marker='x', label='test',color='red')
axes[0].fill_between(x_axis[-preds.shape[0]:], conf_int[:, 0], conf_int[:, 1],
                     alpha=0.2, color='m' ,label = 'interval')

# fill the section where we "held out" samples in our model fit

axes[0].set_title("Train samples & forecasted test samples")

axes[0].legend(loc='upper left')

# Now add the actual samples to the model and create NEW forecasts
arima.update(test)
new_preds, new_conf_int = arima.predict(n_periods=100, return_conf_int=True)
new_x_axis = np.arange(data.shape[0] + 100)

axes[1].plot(new_x_axis[:data.shape[0]], data, alpha=0.75 , label='train')
axes[1].scatter(new_x_axis[data.shape[0]:], new_preds, alpha=0.4, marker='o' , label='new forecast' ,color='lime')
axes[1].fill_between(new_x_axis[-new_preds.shape[0]:],
                     new_conf_int[:, 0],
                     new_conf_int[:, 1],
                     alpha=0.2, color='lime',label = 'interval')
axes[1].set_title("Added new observed values with new forecasts")

axes[1].legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

---

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

You are making two mistakes:

1. you train a model with a constant exogenous variable.
2. your forecast horizon object `fh` does not make sense as it has values <= 0.

---

This code works:

```py
from sktime.forecasting.arima import AutoARIMA
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random(365 * 2,)
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': data})
df['daily_growth'] = np.random.random(365 * 2,)
fh = [1,2,3,4]

arima = AutoARIMA()
arima.fit(df.y, X=df.daily_growth)

forecast_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(fh)))
forecast_df['daily_growth'] = 8 / 365

preds_with_X = arima.predict(fh=fh, X=forecast_df.daily_growth)
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: X array dims (n_rows) != n_periods. Received n_rows=0 and n_periods=4`